# Disable last td on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have django template as follows :

```
<table id="members-table" class="table table-hover table-vcenter">
    <thead>
       <tr>
          <th>Fullname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
          <th>Status</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="members_list">
         {% for member in members %}
             <tr data-member-row class="members-row" data-member-id={{ member.user_id }}>
                 <td>{{ member.user__first_name }} </td>
                  <td>{{ member.user__email }}</td>
                  <td data-member-status data-member-id={{ member.user_id }}>
                      <form method="POST">
                          <div class="checkbox" style="float: left;">
                                <input id="member-status-{{ member.user_id }}" class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" {% if member.active %} checked {% endif %}>
                                <label id="status-label-{{ member.user_id }}"> {% if member.active %} Active {% else %} Inactive {% endif %}</label>
                          </div>
                       </form>
                   </td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
      </tbody>
 </table>
```

The jquery snippet is as follows :

```
$('#members_list').on('click', '[data-member-row]', function (e) {
    var member_id = e.currentTarget.dataset['memberId'];
    alert(member_id)
})
```

Thus I want to get the `data-member-id` from table row which is clicked. With this code I get is  and that is fine, but the problem is that I want to prevent it if **the last td** of the `table row` is clicked.

If the last is clicked I do something else. Thus, I need to not allow this `alert(member_id)` to execute if the last td is clicked.

Any advice?

Comment: Try this one .. 

 trs = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName('tr');
    tds = trs[trs.length - 1].getElementsByTagName('td');
    td = tds[tds.length - 1];

Comment: Instead of listening for a row click, listen for a cell click and then check if it's the last one before doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#members_list').on('click', '[data-member-row]', function (e) {
 if(!e.currentTarget.nextElementSibling){
  doSomethingElse(); return;
 }
 var member_id = e.currentTarget.dataset['memberId'];
 alert(member_id)
})
```

Comment: I still see the alert if I click on the last td.

Comment: explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the [`not:last` selector.](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(#member_list td:not(:last-child)).click()
```

Comment: Try to run the selector in the console and see which elements you get.
$(#member_list td:not(:last-child))

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..

```
trs = document.getElementById(tableId).getElementsByTagName('tr');
tds = trs[trs.length - 1].getElementsByTagName('td');
td = tds[tds.length - 1];
console.log(td.text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an event listener on the row, have it on the cell...

```
$('#members_list').on('click', 'td', function () {

    if ($(this).parent().find('td').last().index() === $(this).index()) {

        // last td was clicked

    } else {

        var member_id = $(this).parent().attr('member-id');
        alert(member_id)

    };

});
```